# How can check history information for a certain customer by using scripting in NetSuite?

Tags: scripting, netsuite

I want to create a Script in NetSuite which needs some history information from a customer. In fact the information I need is to know if the user has purchased an item.
For this, I would need in some way to access to the history of this customer.

Pablo.

Comment: If you are using the _Stage_ field on the Customer record appropriately, then any Customer record that has a _Stage_ of _Customer_ should have purchased something. In the event you're not using the Stage field this way, then this doesn't seem like it would be a difficult search to build.

What is your definition of "user has purchased an item"? Is it that there is a Sales Order present for this Customer? An Invoice? A Cash Sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including this function and passing customer's internalID and item internalID

```
function hasPurchasedBefore(customerInternalID, itemInternalID){
    var results = [];
    var filters = [];
    var columns = [];

    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalidnumber', 'customermain', 'equalto', [customerInternalID]))
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('anylineitem', null, 'anyof', [itemInternalID]));
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('type', null, 'anyof', ['CustInvc']));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', null, 'GROUP'));

    results = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, filters, columns);

    if (results && results.length){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(),nlapiGetRecordId());
var customerInternalID = record.getFieldValue('entity');
var itemInternalID = record.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', 1); //Gets line 1 item Internal ID

if( hasPurchasedBefore(customerInternalID, itemInternalID) ) {
    //Has bought something before
}
```

Comment: Hi Adolfo thanks for the script, it did not work actually. It always gets that customer never bought an item. By the way from where I can get all the entities to search in? like Customers, sales, transaction etc? thanks again buddy

Comment: Here's the types, you can add them on your filter: http://blog.prolecto.com/2014/01/03/netsuite-searchfilter-internal-transaction-type-codes/

Comment: Thanks Adolfo.. I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a saved search `nlapiLoadSearch` or `nlapiCreateSearch` for `invoices`, filtered by customer, and also reporting invoice items (or just a particular item). Using `nlapiCreateSearch` can be tricky to use, so I'd recommend building the saved search using the UI, then load it using `nlapiLoadSeach(type, id)`

This will give you an array of invoices/customers that bought your item.